# Excel Table for grading

Tags: excel

Im trying to do this but im super lost so i need help.
Im a teacher and get the answers of students online.
They are all multiple choice questions. Q1:a Q2:c Q3:b etc
i want to do this table for 10 students
one row MY answers, correct answers
and 10 rows of students answers, id copy and paste their answers to the rows.

what i want to do and no idea how to, is for excel to highlight the wrong answers from students (no need to correct them, just highlight them) highlight, show in different color, etc. 
just need excel to show me what is wrong from the students so i can get a score like 30/40 correct.

there are 7 levels so will have to do the same in 7 sheets with different correct answers in the first column

I have hundreds of students to correct and gets mega tedious to go one by one to correct them in different test levels.
PLEASEEE help me that test are coming and im already dying here
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: use an if statement in excel.http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135455/how-to-highlight-cells-based-on-another-cells-value-in-excel-2011

Comment: I have a soft spot for teachers, as my wife is a teacher.  However, you should know that following the rules is important.  One of the core rules of Stack Overflow is that you have either tried to solve the problem and are stuck or can't complete a programming project because of a technical question/bug/error.  The most important part is that your post is a specific question rather than a broad "help me do the whole project" or "get me on the right path".  These don't help future users with specific problems they are facing.  [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thank you! just wanted to be pointed in the right direction because i was extremly lost. will keep it in mind for the next time!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional formatting:

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules -> Format only cells that contain

Change the dropdowns to Cell Value -> Not Equal To -> Select your answer.

You can do this on a row by row basis one time and then you will be able to paste in your student answers ("Paste Values") and it should work for you.

If you would prefer some VBA code, I can provide that as well.